Is this considered a halfwave dipole?
Is this antenna considered a halfwave dipole and doesn’t need grounding? If I mount this on a metal chassis, do I need a plastic isolator?


nobody can say that without looking inside. You will have to open it.

The max gain of 5.x dB for this dipole antenna uses a large ground plane 30x30 cm. Without that <1 dB.  Read the datasheet.   I Guess its not a simple rubber ducky.

λ/4 Marconian dipole.
